# jQuery/AJAX changes my variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got AJAX request but for some reason the jQuery is changing the variable passed to it, here is the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">              
  function ResolveName(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url : 'resolvename.php',
      data:{"id":id},
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        alert(id);
        $('#'+id).html(data);
      }
    });
  }  
</script>
```

So the button which initiates this is (the variable in ResolveName is different in each button ofc.

```
<span id="76561198031633135"><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" onclick="ResolveName(76561198031633135)">Resolve</button></span>
```

As you see in my JavaScript I do an alert(id) which returns **76561198031633140** not **76561198031633135** which is the id passed

I am totally lost so any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you pass a number and that number is truncated. Pass a string instead:

```
onclick="ResolveName('76561198031633135')"
```